# Python/Cython trouble importing files and methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, importerror

There are 2 issues both relating to importing that may or may not be cython related?

I have the following simplified files to recreate the problem.  All files are in the same directory.  The .pyx files have successfully compiled into `*.so`, `*.pyc` and `*.c` files.

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("*.pyx"),
)
```

cy1.pyx: (cython)

```
cdef int timestwo(int x):
    return x * 2
```

cy1.pxd:

```
cdef int timestwo(int x)
```

cy3.py: (normal python)

```
def tripleit(x):
    return x*3
```

go.py:

```
from cy1 import timestwo
print str(timestwo(5))
```

Gives me the error:  ImportError: cannot import name timestwo

if I change it to:

go.py:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import cy1
print str(cy1.timestwo(5))
```

it tells me: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timestwo'

if I take out the cython all together and try to use normal python call from cy3.py:

go.py:

```
import cy3
print str(cy3.tripeleit(3))
```

I get: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tripeleit'

and last if I do:

go.py:

```
from cy3 import tripleit
print str(tripeleit(3))
```

I get:

```
NameError: name 'tripeleit' is not defined
```

Sorry if this is super basic but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: did you try the answers below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that in `go.py`:

```
from cy1 import timestwo
print str(timestwo(5))
```

you are trying to import a function defined as `cdef`.

To expose this function to Python you have to either use `def` or `cpdef`. Possibly you have to keep as `cdef` in order to `cimport` from other Cython files, justifying why you also have the `pxd` file. In that case I usually have a `C`-like function and a wrapper that can be called from Python.

In this case your `cy1.pyx` file would look like:

```
cdef int ctimestwo(int x):
    return x * 2

def timestwo(x): # <-- small wrapper to expose ctimestwo() to Python
    return ctimestwo(x)
```

and your `cy1.pxd` file:

```
cdef int ctimestwo(int x)
```

such that you can `cimport` only the `ctimestwo` function.

Comment: Thank you Saullo this helped me a lot.  It is exactly what I needed to do.  Also for anyone finding this later, there can be issues with ipython notebook impporting the files if they change.  The %reload_ext cythonmagic doesn't always seem to work, but restarting the kernal helped me.

Comment: that solution kills all speed advantages of cython

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad Actually not. I'm just wrapping a function in order to expose it. But the function itself is fast, and so will be the wrapper... Your downvote is unjustifiable

Comment: Actually, yes you are at the end where it is called from python it makes no difference.

Comment: after compiling with `cythonize -a -i cython_hdr.pyx` and trying to add these wrapper functions in, when I again try to run the above command I get a bunch of `no suitable method found` errors.  Unfortunately I am having issues with installing disutils so using a `setup.py` is in the works.  
`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second error, you have a typo:

```
print str(tripeleit(3))
```

It should be:

```
print str(tripleit(3))
```

Comment: thank you avi you are absolutely right.  I think for my other questions it is related to a difference between cdef and cpdef in the pyx and pxd.  I think I must define the functions as cpdef if they are able to be called from python code but I'm still a bit foggy on it because it seems like all the documentation points to defining these methods as cdef and I read there is a performance issue with cpdef so maybe someone can clarify?