# Error accesing to a method of a class in a list: AttributeError: 'fib.Edge' object has no attribute 'getOrigin'

Tags: python, list, cython

I'm developing a cython code in order to improve the performance of my python code.

When I try to access to a method of an instance inside in a list, I obtain the next message error:

> xx.getOrigin()
>
> AttributeError: 'fib.Edge' object has no attribute 'getOrigin'

I attach a part of the pyx code, the python and output.

Any of you could help me?

**Code pyx :**

```
#######################################################################
###########################Clase Edge #################################
#######################################################################
cdef class Edge:
    #INSTANCE FIELDS & CONSTRUCTOR */
    cdef Node origin              #origin node
    cdef Node end                 #end node

    def __cinit__(self, originNode, endNode):
      self.origin = originNode
      self.end = endNode

   #GET METHODS */
   cdef Node getOrigin(self):
      return self.origin


#######################################################################
###########################Clase Route ################################
#######################################################################
cdef class Route:
    #INSTANCE FIELDS & CONSTRUCTOR */
    cdef double costs             #route total costs
    cdef float demand             #route total demand
    cdef list edges               #edges list
    cdef c_array.array center     #

    def __cinit__(self):
       self.edges = []
       self.center = array('f', [0,1])

   #SET METHODS
   cdef void setEdges(self,list e):
     self.edges =  e

   #LIST GET METHODS*/
   cdef list getEdges(self):
      return self.edges

def prueba():
   print "llega"
   nodo1 = Node(1, 2, 3, 4)
   nodo2 = Node(2, 2, 3, 4)
   nodo3 = Node(3, 2, 3, 4)

   lazo = Edge(nodo1,nodo2)
   lazo2 = Edge(nodo1,nodo3)

   d = lazo2.getOrigin()
   print d

   #pruebo rutas
   ruta = Route()
   lista = []

   lista.append(lazo)
   lista.append(lazo2)

   ruta.setEdges(lista)

   listaa = ruta.getEdges()
   print lista

   #lista
   for xx in listaa:
     print "sss "
     print xx
     n = xx.getOrigin()

###code python .py
import fib
fib.prueba()
```

**Output:**

```
MBP-de-javier:cython javier$ python mydebug.py 

`llega`

 `<fib.Node object at 0x102546668>`

`[<fib.Edge object at 0x102546738>, <fib.Edge object at 0x1025467a0>]`

`sss` 

`<fib.Edge object at 0x102546738>`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

  `File "mydebug.py", line 3, in <module>`

    `fib.prueba()`

  `File "fib.pyx", line 317, in fib.prueba (fib.c:5016)`

   ` xx.getOrigin()`

`AttributeError: 'fib.Edge' object has no attribute 'getOrigin'`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Cython C functions from Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738550/calling-cython-c-functions-from-python)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417762/python-cython-trouble-importing-files-and-methods it's a common problem

Comment: (Actually, I don't think it's quite a duplicate but the answer is there. It's definitely been asked before)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong editing code. I have edited the post with the correct code